# image preview before uploading -IOS

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to setup up an app to allow user to capture a photo and preview on canvas before uploading.  So far i have been able to capture image and place onto canvas(android chrome), but when it comes to ios using safari i am having no such luck (tried Ipad, 5C)

here is the script i have manage to piece together thanks to the help of stackoverflow community (many thanks)

The issue I am having is that when i choose selected image it should display in my iframe (as it does in chrome)  when i try safari it shows no image after selecting

here is a sample link to my app 
    [SampleAPP](http://i-audit-jci.com/previewimagea7)
HTML

```
<img src="" id="image">
<input id="input" type="file" onchange="handleFiles()">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>

function handleFiles()
{
var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files;
var file = filesToUpload[0];

// Create an image
var img = document.createElement("img");
// Create a file reader
var reader = new FileReader();
// Set the image once loaded into file reader
reader.onload = function(e)
{
    img.src = e.target.result;

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");


    var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
    var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;

    if (width > height) {
      if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
        width = MAX_WIDTH;
      }
    } else {
      if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
      }
    }
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById('image').src = dataurl;     
}
// Load files into file reader
reader.readAsDataURL(file);


// Post the data
/*
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("name", "some_filename.jpg");
fd.append("image", dataurl);
fd.append("info", "lah_de_dah");
*/
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: What is purpose of calling `.drawImage()` twice?

Comment: Yess never noticed will edit above, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove using `<canvas>` and set existing `<img>` `src` to `e.target.result` : `data URI` of uploaded `File` object at `FileReader()` `load` event.

You can defined variable `width`, use `if` condition at `#image` `load` event when new `src` is set to check `#image` `.naturalWidth` property, if value is greater than `width` , set `#image.width` to `width` variable.

```html
<img src="" id="image">
<input id="input" type="file" onchange="handleFiles()">
<script>
  var img = document.getElementById("image");
  var width = 400;
  function handleFiles() {
    var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files;
    var file = filesToUpload[0];

    // Create a file reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // Set the image once loaded into file reader
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      img.onload = function() {
        if (this.naturalWidth > width) {
          this.width = width;
        }
      }
      img.src = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, so now i have image in both android and ios, but the image is very large, any way to resize.  Ihave replaced my code with your snippet and have updated the webApp above for viewing (it is a new link)

Comment: @INOH What should `<img>` `width` and `height` be set to, respectively?

Comment: 400 x 300 would fit my iframe nicely

Comment: See updated post. You could also set `height` by checking if `#image.naturalHeight` is greater than `height`, where `var height = 300`

Comment: guest271314, i cannot thankyou enough, i have been struggling for aweek to figure this out, i am just stubborn should have turned to the community first.  All the best and thanks, I have accepted your answer as correct.  thanks again